# Play 2.0 - checking if passed parameter is null

Tags: scala, view, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a little project using Play 2.0 and scala and having a bit struggle in display logic. I would like to check if my passed parameter is empty in my view engine.

I tried:

```
@if(pmem.isEmpty()) {
 there are no past members who won in this branch
} else {
 <table>
etcc...
 <table>
}
```

but it didn't work and gave me a

> **Boolean does not take parameters** error

i also tried

```
@if(pmem == null) {
 there are no past members who won in this branch
} else {
    } else {
     <table>
    etcc...
     <table>
    }
```

and it didn't work, maybe I'm missing something? Or I could be doing it all wrong. I'm using Scala/Play 2.0 framework.

Comment: `@if(pmem.isEmpty) {` gave me the answer

Comment: what Is the type of the "pmem" variable Is It a collection? you might try to debug and get the value of this variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
@if(pmem.isEmpty) {
 there are no past members who won in this branch
} else {
 <table>
etcc...
 <table>
}
```

tried and gave me the answer :)